# Using my Show/Hide JQuery function in a mobile view and tablet view

Tags: jquery, css, html, function, dreamweaver

So I am trying to use my Show hide function for a mobile view and also tablet view, but I am not sure how to implement it. This is my Show Hide function:

```
$(function() {
    $('h2 + p').hide();
    $('h2').click(function(e) {
        var para = $(this).next('p');
        para.toggle();
        if (para.css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/arrow-r.png)');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/arrow-down.png)');
        }
    })
    .css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
```

I want to use this code for my headings 2 but only in mobile view and tablet view, as I have a video on hide until you click the heading. Any thoughts on how to implement it?

From the first answer I now have this code but it still doesn't seem to be working? ;

```
<script>
$(function () {

if($(window).width() < 768 ) {  
    $('h2 + p').hide();
    $('h2').click(function(e) {
        var para = $(this).next('p');
        para.toggle();
        if (para.css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/arrow-r.png)');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/arrow-down.png)');
        }
    })
           .css('cursor', 'pointer');   
});
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake in my code. it  should be ".width()" not ".width"

Comment: The code itself works fine as I am currently using it for another part of my main desktop page (hiding h2 within h3) however using this code above clashes with the h2&h3 hide because it's not set as a mobile/tablet view

Answer (score 0):

Decide a break-point and then do something like below

```
$(function () {

if($(window).width() < 768 ) { // 768 represents break-point measure

// Do whatever you want here

}

});
```

`768px` usually covers Ipad(portrait) down to other small devices.